# Creating and using multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, using

```
         $breakfast = array(
                               'rest_id' => $rest_id  ,
                               'type' => 'Breakfast' ,
                               'value' => $bprice  
                                );



            $lunch = array(
                               'rest_id' => $rest_id  ,
                               'type' => 'Facilities' ,
                               'value' => $lprice  
                                );


            $dinner = array(
                               'rest_id' => $rest_id  ,
                               'type' => 'Facilities' ,
                               'value' => $dprice  
                                );

            $data = $breakfast . $lunch . $dinner;
```

Is the way i created the array $data correct? If yes... now how do i get the array breakfast inside it, if i want to pass it to one function?

I want to do something like this:

```
$this->db->insert_breakfast($breakfast);
```

So how do i get breakfast array out of $data now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `$breakfast`, `$lunch` and `$dinner` to make a multi-dimensional array in `$data`, you will need to replace your assignment with the following.

```
$data = array('breakfast' => $breakfast, 'lunch' => $lunch, 'dinner' => $dinner);
```

Then you can access any of them like `$data['breakfast']['value']`.

I didn't quite understand the DB part. Comment back and I'd be glad to help.

Comment: re: DB; I think it might be CodeIgniter.

Comment: Ahh, not familiar with that. I guess I should be, someone down voted me for that earlier ;)

Comment: Heh. Yeah, shame on you for not knowing the intricacies of all available frameworks! And to top it off, trying to be helpful?!? Pfft ;)

Answer (score 3):

The correct is

```
$data = array($breakfast, $lunch, $dinner);
```

The `.` operator means string concatenation. You can access `$breakfast` with `$data[0]`, since it's the first member. You can also use associative arrays; see @Jason's answer.